# How to force the range of 2 timestamps in a row

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I need to capture two different timestamps, one for incoming_patients and the other one for outcoming_patients. I need to constrain that the outcoming_patient timestamp must be later than the incoming one.

```
create table hold (
incoming_date timestamp,
outcoming_date timestamp CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM incoming_date) > (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM outcoming_date)),
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it sql server?

Comment: Why are you only checking the hour and not minutes, seconds, day, year and month as well? If the incoming_date should be later that the outcoming_date you should simply use `check  (outcoming_date > incoming_date)`?

Comment: Hi. thanks for responses.
im on mysql, i'll post solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @T.S i didn't get the good meaning of timestamp.

I did a big research on SO trying to get how to compare two timestamps and that's not what i really need. This was the first trouble, the second was that I escalated my own doubts. So it was easier.

```
create table hold (    
    incoming_date DATETIME,
    outcoming_date DATETIME check (outcoming_date>incoming_date),
);
```

Comment: You need at least MySQL 8.0. **16** otherwise that check constraint will silently be ignored